# Error on an Event

Tags: bukkit, eventhandler

Using CraftBukkit 1.7.9

Hello,

Whenever I type in a sign "Minigame", it simply will not work.

Here is my code:

```
package me.pvpcraftnetwork.customjoinsigns;


import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.block.SignChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
        public final HashMap<Location, String> signs =  new HashMap<Location, String>();

        public static Main plugin;

        public void onEnable(){
            plugin = this;
            getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been enabled!");
        }

        public void onDisable() {
            plugin = null;
            getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been disabled!");
        } 
        @EventHandler
        public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent event){
            if(event.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Minigame")) {
                signs.put(event.getBlock().getLocation(), event.getPlayer().getName());
                event.getPlayer().sendMessage("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} Custom Join Sign created! Now type in: /cjs [Custom Join Sign Arena Number] setarenaname");
            }
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event){
            Player player = event.getPlayer();  
            if(signs.containsKey(event.getBlock().getLocation()) && !signs.containsValue(event.getPlayer().getName()) || !player.isOp()) {
                event.setCancelled(true);   
            } else {
                signs.remove(event.getBlock().getLocation());
            }
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event){
            Player player = event.getPlayer();
            if(signs.containsKey(event.getClickedBlock().getLocation())) {
                player.teleport(player.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());
            }
        }
    }
```

On the first event, I want it like this:

Whenever I type in a sign "Minigame", it sends the message.

However, I also want it "`if(player.isOp());`" (If the player is an Op on the server), and I don't know where to put it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not registering events. In your `Main` class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`), you need to add this in your `onEnable()`:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new <listener class>());
```

So, in your case, you should add this:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

So your `onEnable()` and `onDisable()` methods should look like this:

```
public void onEnable(){
  plugin = this;

  this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

  getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been enabled!");
}

public void onDisable() {
  plugin = null;
  getLogger().info("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} has been disabled!");
}
```

You should put the `if(player.isOp())` like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent event){
  boolean isOp = event.getPlayer().isOp();//I don't know what you want to do with this, so, you could just use this boolean to check if the player is an op or not
  if(event.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("Minigame")) {
    signs.put(event.getBlock().getLocation(), event.getPlayer().getName());
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage("[PvpCraft Network] {Custom Join Signs} Custom Join Sign created! Now type in: /cjs [Custom Join Sign Arena Number] setarenaname");
  }
}
```